# I cannot get my image and my 'About me' span to stay on the right side of the page whenever I put paragraph underneath it

Tags: html, css

I want to to put a paragraph underneath my image but whenever i do that the whole image and the text above it move to the middle of the page. Does anyone know how it can stay on the right side of the page.

You can see below that the image stayed on the right side of the page **before** i put a paragraph beneath it.
[image]

(This is the code i have used to make it go to the right side of the page.)

```css
.benard {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 margin-right: 30px;
}

.selina {
 margin-top: 80px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
div class="benard">
 <div class="selina"><span class="about">About me</span><br>
  <img src="arms crossed.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">

 </div>
</div>
```

But whenever i put a paragraph beneath the image both elements move to the middle of the page as you can see below.

[image]

(Here is the code i used for this.)

```css
.benard {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 margin-right: 30px;
}

.selina {
 margin-top: 80px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}

p {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="benard">
 <div class="selina"><span class="about">About me</span><br>
  <img src="arms crossed.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
  <p>My name is Janet Osei. I’m a 37 year old full time mom and blogger. I’m a hardworking and enthusiastic woman who is extremely passionate about fashion and fitness.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

I would like my paragraph to stay underneath my image like this.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about setting the width of the p tag according to the width of the image?

```css
.benard {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 margin-right: 30px;
}

.selina {
 margin-top: 80px;
 display: block;
 text-align: center;
}

p {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="benard">
 <div class="selina"><span class="about">About me</span><br>
  <img src="arms crossed.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
  <p>My name is Janet Osei. I’m a 37 year old full time mom and blogger. I’m a hardworking and enthusiastic woman who is extremely passionate about fashion and fitness.</p>
 </div>
</div>
```